# glassfish get shibboleth sp attribute on iis

Tags: glassfish, http-redirect, iis-10, shibboleth-sp

I was able to get the information returned by Shibboleth through the program deployed above IIS (code below).

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
Response.Write("<h3>Server Variables</h3>");
Response.Write("mail= " + Request["mail"] + "<br>");
Response.Write("name = " + Request["name"] + "<br>");
%>
```

However, I can't get the authentication information when I jump to glassfish with the following Settings

```
<httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="https://glassfish.fujitsu.com:8443/info" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found" />
```

After investigation, it was found that when IIS, the information returned by shibboleth could only exist in the request header.

What can I do to make the information available to glassfish's application

My environment is as follows
OS: windows 2016
IIS: 10
GlassFish: 5.1.0

and my shibboleth2.xml is as follows:

```
<ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="true" useHeaders="true">
<SSO entityID="http://adfs-srv.fujitsu.com/adfs/services/trust"
 discoveryProtocol="SAMLDS" discoveryURL="https://ds.example.org/DS/WAYF">
              SAML2
 </SSO>
...
```

attribute-map.xml's setting is as follow:

```
<Attribute name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" id="mail" />
<Attribute name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" id="name" />
```

The browser returns the result of the iis program is as follow:

```
Server Variables

mail= ***@cn.**.com
name= y*
```

thanks!!
waiting for your help!

Comment: in my opinion, we can not forward information using HTTP redirect.you could try to implemet this by using javascript.

Comment: @dayao From the cybersecurity perspective, you can NOT redirect the user info to establish the HTTP login session for Glassfish application. I have updated my answer to provide the resolution on how to pass the request-header information to Glassfish in StackOverflow question [how Iis USES saml2.0 to access adfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552603/how-iis-uses-saml2-0-to-access-adfs).

Comment: @Jalpa Panchal 
Thanks for your answer . can you describe it in more detail?

Comment: use javascript in your code to forward information using that.